# Search For Partial Words With a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help for the bio page of a dating site I am working on.

I have a text field called "bio" full of, you guessed it, text! :)

If i search the bio filed for "stocks", I want to get both the rows which contain the word "stocks" and the rows which contain the word "stockings", or "stocking".

I do it like this (which should work):

```
AND bio LIKE '%stocks%' // this query should return both the rows which contain "stocks" and "stockings", right? What I am doing wrong?
```

How can I do this?
Ty!:)

Comment: did you mean `'%stock%'`? The extra `s` would definitely not match stockings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well '%stocks%' will certainly not find 'stockings' - how about dropping the 's' and using '%stock%'? 'stocks' is not part of 'stockings', but that is how LIKE works.

Comment: OMG i am so silly:) I must be tired working for 12 hours, maybe I'll delete the question

Answer (score 1):

"stocks" has an "s" after the "k". "stocking" has an "i" after the "k". To get the matches you're seeking, you'd need to search for just `'%stock%'`.

Answer (score 0):

stocks
stockings
stocking

the common part is `stock`, so you have to search for "`%stock%`" if you want to match all three.

you can also do something like "`%stock%s%`" which would match both "stocks" and "stockings" or "stocking is". you get the picture.

alternatively you could just use the `match("text to match") against column` syntax, but you have to full-text index `column`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use full text search in mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html